# Why wont my DELL laptop take the product key on the COA sticker?

Tags: dell-inspiron, license-key, validation

I was given an old DELL 1050 Inspiron laptop and I didn't have the original XP SP2 CD that came with it and so I just installed with a copy of XP that I had in the house.  During install I tried to put in the CD key on the sticker that is on the  bottom of the laptop but it wouldn't accept it and so I continued the install using my XP cd key on the install I had.   So, now I am installed and updated to SP3 but I am still unable to use the Windows Product Key update tool to change the CD key of the system.

WHy am I not able to do this.  Is there a way to figure out why the CD key on the bottom of the laptop wouldn't work?  Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you certain that they're both of the same edition (home vs. professional)?

Comment: The Dell is probably using an OEM license.  If you tried to install from a retail CD, it won't take it.  Does the CD have "FPP" in its name when you view it in explorer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your key is probably an OEM [SLP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Locked_Preinstallation) key which is unlikely to work with a retail CD or  System Builder OEM CD.